# Transpose in HIVE SQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I am trying to transpose like below.

```
clm_nb                              part_nb 
008195066                           20401
008195066                           20411
008195179                           89598
008195179                           89599
008195277                           56478
008195277                           56477

clm_nb                              part_nb                part_nb
008195066                           20401                    20411
008195179                           89598                    89599
008195277                           56477                    56477
```

Comment: the titles are the fields and the numbers are the records doesn't look like it came through correctly on the question   basically clm_nb and part_nb are the two fields and i want clm_nb, part_nb, part_nb, etc.... if more than two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking to your data seems you need  in in the first column max in the second eg:

```
  select clm_nb ,  min(part_nb) min_part, max(part_nb) max_part
  from my_table 
  group by  clm_nb
```

Comment: Expression not in GROUP BY key 'clm_nb' error message

Comment: answer upodated .. clm_nb

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit and it worked, but quick question, what if there are more than two that i need to bring over let's say 4 because i could have up to 10

Comment: this is another question  ..in the case you mention in comment  the sue of aggregation function is not enough  if you need more  . values . you must build a pivot table  .. this is not easy in mysql  and you should probably use dynamic sql for generated  the code  .. you need ..